# How do I convert unicode codepoints to their character representation?

Tags: java, unicode

How do I convert strings representing code points to the appropriate character?

For example, I want to have a function which gets `U+00E4` and returns `ä`.

I know that in the character class I have a function `toChars(int codePoint)` which takes an integer but there is no function which takes a string of this type.

Is there a built in function or do I have to do some transformation on the string to get the integer which I can send to the function?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Code points are written as hexadecimal numbers prefixed by `U+`

So,you can do this

```
int codepoint=Integer.parseInt(yourString.substring(2),16);
char[] ch=Character.toChars(codepoint);
```

Comment: Can you get a single Java Character instead of an array of char?

Comment: @k-den Yes, with something like `new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(codepoint).toString().charAt(0)`, but be aware that codepoints above 64k will result in *two* chars, a high and low surrogate pair. You may prefer to leave off the `.charAt(0)` and simply get the result as a `String`.

Answer (score 12):

The question asked for a function to convert a string value representing a Unicode code point (i.e. `"+Unnnn"` rather than the Java formats of `"\unnnn"` or `"0xnnnn`). However, newer releases of Java have enhancements which simplify the processing of a string contain multiple code points in Unicode format:

- The introduction of Streams in Java 8.
- Method [`public static String toString​(int codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) which was added to the `Character` class in Java 11. It returns a `String` rather than a `char[]`, so `Character.toString(0x00E4)` returns `"ä"`.

Those enhancements allow a different approach to solving the issue raised in the OP. This method transforms a set of code points in Unicode format to a readable `String` in a single statement:

```
void processUnicode() {

    // Create a test string containing "Hello World " with code points in Unicode format.
    // Include an invalid code point (+U0wxyz), and a code point outside the Unicode range (+U70FFFF).
    String data = "+U0048+U0065+U006c+U006c+U0wxyz+U006f+U0020+U0057+U70FFFF+U006f+U0072+U006c+U0000064+U20+U1f601";

    String text = Arrays.stream(data.split("\\+U"))
            .filter(s -> ! s.isEmpty()) // First element returned by split() is a zero length string.
            .map(s -> {
                try {
                    return Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
                    System.out.println("Ignoring element [" + s + "]: NumberFormatException from parseInt(\"" + s + "\"}");
                }
                return null; // If the code point is not represented as a valid hex String.
            })
            .filter(v -> v != null) // Ignore syntactically invalid code points.
            .filter(i -> Character.isValidCodePoint(i)) // Ignore code points outside of Unicode range.
            .map(i -> Character.toString(i)) // Obtain the string value directly from the code point. (Requires JDK >= 11 )
            .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(text); // Prints "Hello World "
}
```

And this is the output:

```
run:
Ignoring element [0wxyz]: NumberFormatException from parseInt("0wxyz"}
Hello World 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Notes:

- With this approach there is no longer any need for a specific function to convert a code point in Unicode format. That's dispersed instead, through multiple intermediate operations in the `Stream` processing. Of course the same code could still be used to process just a single code point in Unicode format.
- It's easy to add intermediate operations to perform further validation and processing on the `Stream`, such as case conversion, removal of emoticons, etc.

Comment: In Java 8 (or: Java 5 and higher) you can use `new String(Character.toChars(i))` instead of `Character.toString(i)`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, that approach would be more in the spirit of the question since the OP had specifically mentioned `Character.toChars(int codePoint)`.

Answer (score 8):

Call [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(int%5B%5D,int,int)) on `String`.

```
"\u00E4"

new String(new int[] { 0x00E4 }, 0, 1);
```

Comment: you are treating it as an int literal.. op have it as a string in the form `U+00E4`

Comment: @Anirudh right, and you dealt with it appropiately. But I wonder whether `"\u00e4"` was known to be equivalent (that is, in java source code). You got +1 from me.

Comment: i guess they are equivalent..but am not sure about this..:)

Answer (score 6):

Converted from Kotlin:

```
    public String codepointToString(int cp) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (Character.isBmpCodePoint(cp)) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        } else if (Character.isValidCodePoint(cp)) {
            sb.append(Character.highSurrogate(cp));
            sb.append(Character.lowSurrogate(cp));
        } else {
            sb.append('?');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but it's really @tateisu's code run through a converter

Comment: alright but, I need to know how to get the `/u` string not the actual value

Comment: Note that StringBuilder has .appendCodePoint()

Answer (score 1):

this example does not use char[].

```
// this code is Kotlin, but you can write same thing in Java
val sb = StringBuilder()
val cp :Int // codepoint
when {
    Character.isBmpCodePoint(cp) -> sb.append(cp.toChar())
    Character.isValidCodePoint(cp) -> {
        sb.append(Character.highSurrogate(cp))
        sb.append(Character.lowSurrogate(cp))
    }
    else -> sb.append('?')
}
```

Comment: You can just use `stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(cp)` instead of this.

Comment: I know. I have prepared this code to explain the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 11, you can do:

```java
jshell> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt("U+00E4".substring(2), 16))
$1 ==> "ä"
```

Answer (score 0):

- you want to display a codepoint?
  or
- you want to convert a codepoint to char datatype?

Well, second part is not possible because codepoint may be of 4 bytes and char datatype can hold only 2 bytes.

So if it may be more generalized approach to never use char data type in java, use int or String instead.

What datatype is used to hold code point?
Single code point can be hold in an int data types.  A unicode String is technically an array of int, rather than array of char.

```
String smiley = new String(new int[] { 0x1F600 }, 0, 1); //int[] array of int codepoints can be converted to string
System.out.println(" print smiley =  "+smiley );
```

output
print smiley =

If you are using IntelliJ idea, You can copy output smiley and paste within double quoted string.  You will get this "\uD83D\uDE00"

If you print this string you again get a smiley

```
System.out.println("\uD83D\uDE00");
```

output

Why we cannot use single "\u" to represent smiley within a string?
Because when \u escape was designed, all unicode chars could be represented by 2 bytes or 4 hexadecimal digits. So there are always 4 hexadecimal digits after \u in a java string literal. To represent a larger value of Unicode you need a larger hexadecimal number but that will break existing java strings. So there java uses same approach as utf-16 representation.

Following 2 are equivalent.

```
String smiley = new String(new int[] { 0x1F600 }, 0, 1); //using single code point number
String smiley = "\uD83D\uDE00";//split code point in 2 parts of 2 bytes each (utf-16)
```

Refer to java doc here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode

> Unicode Character Representations The char data type (and therefore
> the value that a Character object encapsulates) are based on the
> original Unicode specification, which defined characters as
> fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode Standard has since been
> changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more
> than 16 bits. The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to
> U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value. (Refer to the definition of
> the U+n notation in the Unicode Standard.)
>
> The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to
> as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters whose code points
> are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java
> platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the
> String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary
> characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from
> the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the
> low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).
>
> A char value, therefore, represents Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)
> code points, including the surrogate code points, or code units of the
> UTF-16 encoding. An int value represents all Unicode code points,
> including supplementary code points. The lower (least significant) 21
> bits of int are used to represent Unicode code points and the upper
> (most significant) 11 bits must be zero. Unless otherwise specified,
> the behavior with respect to supplementary characters and surrogate
> char values is as follows:
>
> The methods that only accept a char value cannot support supplementary
> characters. They treat char values from the surrogate ranges as
> undefined characters. For example, Character.isLetter('\uD840')
> returns false, even though this specific value if followed by any
> low-surrogate value in a string would represent a letter. The methods
> that accept an int value support all Unicode characters, including
> supplementary characters. For example, Character.isLetter(0x2F81A)
> returns true because the code point value represents a letter (a CJK
> ideograph). In the Java SE API documentation, Unicode code point is
> used for character values in the range between U+0000 and U+10FFFF,
> and Unicode code unit is used for 16-bit char values that are code
> units of the UTF-16 encoding. For more information on Unicode
> terminology, refer to the Unicode Glossary.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi you can use the hex string literal:

```
   writelnuc('maXbox'+#+'ᛗᚨᛪᛒᛟᛪ');
   writeln((#$16D7+#$16A8+#$16EA+#$16D2+#$16DF+#$16EA))
```

or even a smiley with concatenation (last 2 hexadecimal digits=8bytes):

```
   //ᛗᛞЖ
  writeln((#$16D7+#$16DE+#$0416+#$D83D+#$DE00))
```

Answer (score -6):

You can print them

```
s='\u0645\u0635\u0631\u064a'
print(s)
```

Answer (score -7):

The easiest way I've found so far is to just cast the codepoint; if you're just expecting a single char per codepoint, then this might be fine for you.:

```
int codepoint = ...;
char c = (char)codepoint;
```

Comment: If the code point is higher than the maximum value of char, then it will overflow and you will get the wrong code point. I do not think this is a good idea.

Comment: The `char` type has been obsolete in Java for many years (decades?), unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode.