# How to convert Unicode value to character?

Tags: android, utf-8

I am receiving this value (20B9) as currency from the server which is the corresponding sign for Indian Rupee (₹). How to display the currency symbol in a textview from the utf value.?

Below is the JSONObject i receive from server.

```
"currency": {
    "name": "Indian rupee",
    "isoCode": "INR",
    "symbol": "20B9",
    "decimalDigits": 2
  }
```

And I am using the belove function to format the cost of a product

```
  public static String formatAmount(Currency currency, double amount) {
    String currencySymbol =  "\\u"+currency.getSymbol();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    byte[] utf8 = new byte[0];
    try {
        utf8 = currencySymbol.getBytes("UTF-8");
        currencySymbol = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(currencySymbol);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        currencySymbol = currency.getIsoCode();
    }
    return currencySymbol + df.format(amount);
}
```

But I am getting \u20B9 as the output not ₹

Comment: Well what do you see now? Please show complere text. 20B9 does not look like a utf-8 value for me as 20 is the space char.

Comment: 20B9 is the Unicode point value. I.e. U+20B9. When working with JSON, it's valid for the server to escape non-ASCII to Unicode point values with a `\u` prefix. If you are using JSON, a good decoder should decode it, otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380901/how-do-i-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-their-character-presentation

Comment: Please provide some code so that we can help further

Comment: Have updated the code. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`20B9` is a Unicode point value. I.e. U+20B9. It's not encoded and not UTF-8.

It's pointless trying to `currencySymbol.getBytes("UTF-8")` as your string has already been decoded from bytes - all you will get is the ASCII bytes of the string of the hex, hence the response you're getting.

Instead, you need to:

1. Convert the hex to an integer, which represents the Unicode code point
2. Get the char at the given Unicode code point

Example:

```
 int codepoint = Integer.parseInt(currency.getSymbol(), 16);
 char[] currencySymbol =Character.toChars(codepoint);
```